# How to select the pairs of features that have correlation higher than a threshold in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `correlation matrix` which is a `pandas` dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'vars': ['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c', 'col_d'],
                   'col_a': [1, 0.9, 0.04, 0.03],
                   'col_b': [0.9,1,0.05,0.03],
                   'col_c': [0.04, 0.05, 1, -0.04],
                   'col_d': [0.03, 0.03, -0.04,1]})
```

I would like to get all the **unique** "pairs" that on absolute value have a correlation above a certain `threshold` and exclude self correlation

So, if the threshold is `0.8`, I should get something like this:

```
[('col_a', 'col_b')]
```

Any ideas how I could do that ?

Comment: do you want to have the unique pairs? and self correlation?

Comment: Is possible change expected ouput? Because accepted solution not match.

Comment: do you mean tuple/lists?

Comment: @mozway I think jezreal meant that in the expected output I had the full list, whereas actually your solution solves also another problem that I didnt think of. Corrected it now

Comment: OK, then super. Happy coding.

Comment: @jezrael sorry for the confusion. Thanks for the effort and your time !

Comment: Yes, I see your edit now :)

Comment: removed solution, best in future not change question, because not match answers. Best post new question if rapidly change like here.

Comment: @jezrael will do. I am sorry and thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set 'vars' as index, `stack` and use the output for slicing:

```
pairs = foo.set_index('vars').stack()
pairs[pairs.abs().gt(0.8)]
```

output:

```
vars        
col_a  col_a    1.0
       col_b    0.9
col_b  col_a    0.9
       col_b    1.0
col_c  col_c    1.0
col_d  col_d    1.0
```

As list:

```
pairs = foo.set_index('vars').stack()
list(pairs[pairs.gt(0.8)].index)
```

```
[('col_a', 'col_a'), ('col_a', 'col_b'), ('col_b', 'col_a'), ('col_b', 'col_b'), ('col_c', 'col_c'), ('col_d', 'col_d')]
```

If you want to get only the unique pairs (*e.g.*, B vs A == A vs B) and drop self correlation (*e.g.*, A vs A), use this alternative.

[`np.triu`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) enables to keep only one of the triangles in the correlation matrix, and the `k` parameter allows to shift the diagonal (`k=0` keeps the diagonal, `k=1` removes the diagonal, thus if you want to keep self correlation, use `k=0`)

```
import numpy as np
foo = foo.set_index('vars')
pairs = foo.where(np.triu(foo, k=1).astype(bool)).stack()
list(pairs[pairs.abs().gt(0.8)].index)
```

output:

```
[('col_a', 'col_b')]
```

Comment: for the solution without the self correlation the `foo = foo.set_index('vars')` needs to be added after the import of numpy or replace `foo` with `foo.set_index('vars')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop. Try that.
Firstly, drop the vars column and take the correlations.

```
foo = foo.drop('vars', axis = 1).corr()
```

Then with this loop take the correlations between the conditions. 0.8 and 0.99 (to avoid itself)

```
a = []
b = []
for i in foo.columns:
    for ii in range(len(foo.columns)):
        if (foo[i].iloc[ii] > 0.8) and (foo[i].iloc[ii] < 0.99):
            a.append(i)
            b.append(foo[i].iloc[ii])
```

You can see the features and corrs with a and b list.

Then if you want to visualize;

```
df = (foo > 0.95 ) & (foo < 1) 
df.applymap(lambda x: True if x else np.nan).dropna(how = 'all', axis = 1).dropna(how = 'all').fillna('-')
```